# python for loop removing duplicated output data in list

Tags: python-3.x

from a python for loop i get duplicated output data for each iteration.
what i want is to only get the new data in each iteration.

How can i remove the repeated data from the list and only get the not repeated data

the data that gets dublicated is the hours minutes and seconds

sorry for my english .

```
import json

with open('activities.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)

keys = []
values = []
lijst = [[],[]]

def loop():
    for y in d['activities']:
        name = y['name']
        lijst[0].append(name)
        p = y['time_entries']

        for e in p:
            h = e['hours']
            m = e['minutes']
            s = e['seconds']

            lijst[1].append(h)
            lijst[1].append(m)
            lijst[1].append(s)

        print(lijst[1])
        test = dict((k, lijst[1]) for k in [name])

loop()
```

output the first data is repeated in the second list the second is repeated in the third and so on:

[1, 2, 11, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 1]

[1, 2, 11, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 3]

[1, 2, 11, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 14]

Comment: Can you give a sample of your data and what you expect to get from it?

Comment: what do you mean by 'duplicated'? I think it's sort of hard to tell what the problem is without knowing how the input looks like. also, what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reset `lijst` at the begging of each iteration:

```
import json

with open('activities.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)

keys = []
values = []

def loop():
    for y in d['activities']:
        lijst = [[],[]] #reset list
        name = y['name']
        lijst[0].append(name)
        p = y['time_entries']

        for e in p:
            h = e['hours']
            m = e['minutes']
            s = e['seconds']

            lijst[1].append(h)
            lijst[1].append(m)
            lijst[1].append(s)

        print(lijst[1])
        test = dict((k, lijst[1]) for k in [name])

loop()
```